# How to use rack middleware with Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

Hey guys,
I'm trying to make the rack middleware [NotFound](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/master/lib/rack/contrib/not_found.rb) to work with rails3 but I needed to make some changes to return some json, so I basically defined a new class :

```
class NotFound

  def initialize(app, msg, content_type = "text/html")
    @app = app
    @content = msg
    @length = msg.size.to_s
    @content_type = content_type
  end

  def call(env)
    [404, {'Content-Type' => @content_type, 'Content-Length' => @length}, @content]
  end
end
```

I added this class above to "app/middleware/not_found.rb" and add this line below to my application.rb file :

```
config.middleware.use "NotFound", {:error => "Endpoint Not Found"}.to_json, "application/json"
```

and now ... well, it works as I expected ... It always return

```
{"error"=>"Endpoint Not Found"}
```

Now how can I make it work only if the router fails ? I saw there is a insert_after method but can't make it happen after Application.routes

ps : I know I could handle it with the rails3 router, but it's an experiment, I'm just having some fun :-)

Thanks !

Comment: why don't use system of rails instead that. It's more complicated to little stuff.

Comment: you should read the entire question, I mean until the end ... "ps : I know I could handle it with the rails3 router, but it's an experiment, I'm just having some fun"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails router will already return a 404 response when no routes match. If you want to customize that response, I suppose you could do:

```
class NotFound
  def initialize(app, msg, content_type = "text/html")
    @app = app
    @content = msg
    @length = msg.size.to_s
    @content_type = content_type
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

    if status == 404
      [404, {'Content-Type' => @content_type, 'Content-Length' => @length}, @content]
    else
      [status, headers, body]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, I feel dumb now :-)

Comment: Do you know if there's any advantage at using a middleware vs rescue from in ApplicationController ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You may want to ask a new question, with some example code? In general, though, it's best to let Rails handle exceptions, and just set it up to inform you when things go wrong. See hoptoadapp.com for an example.