# Rails 3: How to declare Rack middleware in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rack

Many examples such as these two:

[How to use rack middleware with Rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224900/how-to-use-rack-middleware-with-rails3)

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

define middleware in a class and then add

```
config.middleware.use "ClassNameHere"
```

to `config/application.rb` but I can't figure where in application.rb to add this. I have put it inside of `class Application < Rails::Application`. I am also not sure if there is a  specific location where I put my middleware class. I have mine in /lib.

Say my middleware class is called ResponseTimer, I receive the following error when I run `rake middleware`:
`uninitialized constant ResponseTimer`

Please note that I am in Rails 3.1 and not 2.x which is why I am not putting the config.middleware.use in environment.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to `config/application.rb` See here https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/rails-lib-files.md